# Convert Spring field injection to constructor injection (IntelliJ IDEA)?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

I am convinced to convert my Spring Java field injection [@Autowired] to constructor injection ([among other reasons](http://vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/), to facilitate mock unit testing)...

*Is there a utility I can use to automatically do that Spring field to constructor injection conversion?*

For example, IntelliJ IDEA has generation shortcuts for a lot of things (i.e: generate setters & getters for fields); I'm hoping there's something similar to that... This is particularly useful when it is tedious to do the conversion manually, because a class to be converted already has numerous field-injected fields.

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Nothing out of the box. The way I do is, I do a search and replace for `@Autowired private` to `@Autowired private final`. Then there is a error displayed saying, final fields are not initialized. If you do a autocompletion(Alt+Enter) then it asks if It wants to create a contructor, and then you can select the fields and Enter. Thats it.

Comment: @pvpkiran that sounds like a good workaround.  I will try it on the next chance I get where private is acceptable.

Comment: And I guess I could always change private back to whatever it was, after the auto-constructor completes.

Comment: of course, private is just an example I gave you. It could be any modifier. Main thing is to make the fields final, So that Idea cries with an error and we can kick in auto completion to generate required constructor

Comment: @pvpkiran ingeniously simple fix. Thank you :)

Comment: @cellepo @ meese Let me add it as an aswer, since many people are stumbling upon this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's now implemented in IntelliJ IDEA.

1) Place your cursor on one of the `@Autowired` annotation.

2) Hit `Alt+Enter`.

3) Select `Create constructor`

[image]

This is the [quick fix](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolving-problems.html) related to the [inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-inspection.html) "Field injection warning":

> Spring Team recommends: "Always use constructor based dependency
>   injection in your beans. Always use assertions for mandatory
>   dependencies".
>
> Field injection/NullPointerException example:
>
> ```
> class MyComponent {
>
>   @Inject MyCollaborator collaborator;
>
>   public void myBusinessMethod() {
>     collaborator.doSomething(); // -> NullPointerException   
>   } 
> }
> ```
>
> Constructor injection should be used:
>
> ```
> class MyComponent {
>
>   private final MyCollaborator collaborator;
>
>   @Inject
>   public MyComponent(MyCollaborator collaborator) {
>     Assert.notNull(collaborator, "MyCollaborator must not be null!");
>     this.collaborator = collaborator;
>   }
>
>   public void myBusinessMethod() {
>     collaborator.doSomething(); // -> safe   
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: +1/Accepted for the new 'create constructor' context option!  But question about `Assert#notNull`:  Both two versions of `MyComponent` will throw an Exception of `collaborator` is `null`, so what is the advantage of `Assert#notNull`?  Just a programmer-refine-able message param?  Or maybe guaranteed Exception at Spring-context-load-time, instead of runtime possibility (via #myBusinessMethod)?

Comment: Is there a 1-liner to assert all injected variables non-null?

Comment: @cellepo [Assert#notNull](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Assert.html#notNull-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-) throws an IllegalArgumentException at the construction of the object instead of a NullPointerException at some random point in the execution of the application. It's an application of the [fail fast principle](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/09/15/fail-fast-principle/).

Comment: @cellepo I'm not sure there is  1-liner to assert all injected variables non-null but you can build one.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing out of the box.

The way I do is, I do a search and replace for
`@Autowired private` to 
`@Autowired private final`.

Then there is a error displayed saying, final fields are not initialized.
 If you do a autocompletion(Alt+Enter), then it asks if you want to create a contructor, and then you can select the fields and click Enter.

private is just an example. It could be any modifier. Main thing is to make the fields final, So that Idea cries with an error and we can kick in auto completion to generate required constructor